# How to set a BOOL value that can be used in other files of obj-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to set a BOOL value that needs to be checked within another file where I do the XML parching.

Its like this in filename.m:

```
    if (internetConnectionStatus == NotReachable) {

        //SET A BOOL VALUE TO FALSE

    } else {    

        //SET A BOOL VALUE TO TRUE

    }
```

And in XMLParserfile.m I need to check whether the BOOL value set in filename.m is TRUE or FALSE

```
    if (BOOLVALUEORSOMETHING == TRUE) {

        //DO THIS

    } else {    

        //DO THAT

    }
```

This could be a stupid question, but what is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Use it as a property.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL number;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. I'm not sure your entire goal, so it some cases you might actually want to use static classes or methods instead.

filename.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef enum {
NotReachable
} InternetConnectionStatus;

@interface filename : NSObject
{
    BOOL isReachable;
}

@property BOOL isReachable;

@end
```

filename.m:

```
#import "filename.h"

@implementation filename
@synthesize isReachable;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.        
        InternetConnectionStatus internetConnectionStatus = NotReachable;
        if (internetConnectionStatus == NotReachable) {

            //SET A BOOL VALUE TO FALSE
            self.isReachable = FALSE;

        } else {    

            //SET A BOOL VALUE TO TRUE
            self.isReachable = TRUE;
        }                
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

XMLParserfile.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface XMLParserfile : NSObject

@end
```

XMLParserfile.m:

```
#import "XMLParserfile.h"
#import "filename.h"

@implementation XMLParserfile

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
        filename *file = [[filename alloc] init];

        if(file.isReachable == TRUE)
        {
            // DO THIS
        }
        else
        {
            // DO THAT.
        }
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: It did not work, I guess there is something with the self = [super init];

Comment: `self = [super init];` is perfectly fine

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in one of several ways. I've discussed that in [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257025/how-do-i-connect-a-table-view-to-a-view-controller/6258078#6258078).